# rails updated_at between time now and time 5 minutes ago

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, time

I currently have an Account model in my rails app, within the update action of the AccountsController I would like to check if an account has been updated within the last 5 minutes.

Unless the account has been updated within the last 5 minutes I would like to run a specific action.

In other words, if the account has not been updated within the last 5 minutes -> run action.

Im struggling to get the below code to reflect my summary above, unfortunately depending on which way I construct the method in my model (eg, updated_at > 5.minutes.ago OR updated_at < 5.minutes.ago) it either always runs the action or never runs the action.

Therefore I believe I may have a misunderstanding regarding time and comparison? I need the method to check the last time the account was updated and then decide if this was more than 5 minutes ago from the time now. (eg, 6 mins ago, 7 mins ago etc...) If it is more than 5 minutes ago then run the action! if not (eg, 4 mins ago, 1 min ago, anything under 5 minutes!) then don't run the action?

my accounts controller:

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
    def update
       respond_to do |format|
  if @account.update(account_params)
    unless @account.updated_recently?
      @account.create_activity :update, owner: current_user, recipient: @account
    end
    format.html { redirect_to( @account )}
    format.json { render json: @account }
  else
    format.html { redirect_to edit_account_url(@account), flash: {danger: 'Something went wrong, try again.'} }
    format.json { render nothing:  true }
  end
end
end
end
```

my account model:

```
class Account < Activerecord::Base
  def updated_recently?
    updated_at > 5.minutes.ago
  end
end
```

Many thanks

Comment: If you call `@account.update(account_params)`, which updates `updated_at`, and immediately after that you check if account was `updated_recently?`, it's no wonder you get such behavior.

Comment: Oh yes of course! - I can move this out of '@account.update(account_params)', however what if account fails to update? I will have an action that runs (as my condition is now satisfied) but an account that has not updated - Is there a way to have this run only when the account has a successful update? Thanks

Comment: You can check if it was updated recently before updating, assign it to some local variable and then on the basis of value of this variable decide if you should call `create_activity`.

Comment: I decided that all I wrote on this subject can be bound as an answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error occurs because you call you call `@account.update(account_params)`, which updates updated_at, and immediately after that you check if account was `updated_recently?`. To avoid this, you can check if it was updated recently before updating, assign it to some local variable and then on the basis of value of this variable decide if you should call `create_activity`, something like this:

```
updated_recently = @account.updated_recently?
if @account.update(account_params)
  unless updated_recently
    @account.create_activity :update, owner: current_user, recipient: @account
  end
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

updated_recently = @account.updated_recently?
if @account.update(account_params)
  unless updated_recently
    @account.create_activity :update, owner: current_user, recipient: @account
  end

Comment: Adding a bit more context & explanations to the answer on what it does could be great.